# Is it okay to use a single project for external workflow activities?

Tags: 2013, workflow

SDL Tridion 2013 includes the option to different script types for Automatic Activity Properties:

- VBScript (deprecated and only available for upgrades or if the "Legacy Pack" is installed)
- C#
- External Activity, which references an "external" assembly loaded to a TBB

The external activity requires a setting for:

- `AssemblyTbbId`, set to a TCM URI (tcm-id or WebDAV url)
- `Type` set to your uploaded class's namespace and a class (that inherits from ExternalActivity)

I'm able to create multiple classes, upload everything in a single assembly, then reference the individual classes in my automatic activity properties. But **does it matter if we put these classes within the same Class Library project in Visual Studio?**

The use case would be wanting to manage related code to a workflow within the same project or solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no right answer to this question, it's the same as asking if all your event systems or if all your Template building blocks should all be in the same dll. It is purely an implementer decision.

If you foresee to have different teams working on different flows, then it would make sense to have different DLLs.

If you intend to share classes between various assemblies then you need to start splitting off these "utility" classes into a third assembly that could go in the GAC.

Comment: But as Alvin asked "Is it okay"... the answer is Yes.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Maybe I should have asked "do I have to/should I create a separate Visual Studio project for each *automated activity instance* piece of code" there'd be a stronger "no" answer. :-)